# Image zoom to fit Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox

I have a Bootstrap Grid and images inside. My images aren't the same size, so I get an ugly grid.
I want all the images to look the same size. I want them to be zoomed and to hide the override part of the image.

I'm trying with this code, but no success:

```
<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2'>
    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="url">
        <img class="img-responsive" style='-ms-object-fit: cover; -moz-object-fit: cover; -o-object-fit: cover; -webkit-object-fit: cover;  object-fit: cover;  overflow: hidden; -ms-transition: 1s all; -moz-transition: 1s all; -o-transition: 1s all; -webkit-transition: 1s all; transition: 1s all;' alt=""  src="url">
    </a>
</div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
```

I know its not clean to put the style right there, but just for tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

JS:

```
function squareThumbs() {
  var thumbs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

  for (i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
    if (thumbs[i].parentNode.className.indexOf("thumbnail") != -1){
      thumbs[i].style.height = thumbs[i].clientWidth + "px";
      console.log(thumbs[i].clientWidth);
      console.log(thumbs[i].clientHeight);
    }
    console.log(thumbs[i].parentNode.className);
  }
}
squareThumbs();
window.onresize = squareThumbs;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
  <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="#" style="overflow:hidden;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x125" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;-ms-object-fit: cover; -moz-object-fit: cover; -o-object-fit: cover; -webkit-object-fit: cover;  object-fit: cover;  overflow: hidden; -ms-transition: 1s all; -moz-transition: 1s all; -o-transition: 1s all; -webkit-transition: 1s all; transition: 1s all;" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Live Demo: http://www.bootply.com/bg1A4I9IJ0